# How to calculate the volume of $(\frac{x}{a}+\frac{y}{b})^2+(\frac{z}{c})^2 \le 1$ for a,b,c is the real number?

Tags: integration, geometry

How to imagine or draw this geometry?
And how to calculate its volume?
Forevermore, can we calculate its surface area?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadric#Euclidean_space

Comment: Rotate the surface by the angle $\arctan(b, a)$ around the $z$ axis. You get $(1/a^2 +1/b^2) x^2 + z^2 = 1$, which is a right elliptic cylinder, unbounded along its axis.

Comment: Perhaps a typo, $c$ cannot disappear.

Comment: You sure it should not be $(x/a)^2+(y/b)^2+(z/c)^2\leq 1$?

Comment: @Narasimham Right, $(1/a^2 + 1/b^2) x^2 +(z/c)^2 = 1$, this rotation obviously doesn't affect $z$.

Comment: @mickep thx, I correct this mistake : )

Comment: @ Maxim Apologies.. One of the three terms can vanish completely as it is an elliptic cylinder after rotation to align cylinder and coordinate axes.. –

Answer (score 0):

[image]

After rotation of cylinder axis to make it parallel to coordinate axis  it is found to be an infinite length elliptic cylinder. For prismatic/extruded sections we have

Volume

$$ =\pi p\,c L $$

where

$$ \dfrac{1}{p^2}=\dfrac{1}{a^2}+\dfrac{1}{b^2} $$

and cylinder length $ =L$ (not specifically given) and surface area likewise is ellipse perimeter $ 4 a E(e) $ in terms of complete elliptic integral of second kind multiplied by length $L$.